# How can I conditionally pass a subshell through 'time'?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, time

I have a setup script for a Vagrant box where I used to measure single steps with `time`. Now I would like to conditionally enable or disable the time measurements.

For example, previously a line would look like:

```
time (apt-get update > /tmp/last.log 2>&1)
```

Now I thought I could simply do something like this:

```
MEASURE_TIME=true
[[ $MEASURE_TIME = true ]] && TIME="time --format=%e" || TIME=""

$TIME (apt-get update > /tmp/last.log 2>&1)
```

But this won't work:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `apt-get'
`$TIME (apt-get update > /tmp/last.log 2>&1)'
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: You just need reach target velocity for the **[flux capacitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeLorean_time_machine#Flux_capacitor)** to work ;)

Comment: @goldilocks You mean the [magnet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/11/19/10574048.aspx)? ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be able to *time* a subshell, you need the `time` *keyword*, not command.

The `time` keyword, part of the language, is only recognised as such when entered literally and as the first word of a command (and in the case of `ksh93`, then the next token doesn't start with a `-`). Even entering `"time"` won't work let alone `$TIME` (and would be taken as a call to the `time` command instead).

You could use aliases here which are expanded before another round of parsing is performed (so would let the shell recognise that `time` keyword):

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias time_or_not=
TIMEFORMAT=%E

MEASURE_TIME=true
[[ $MEASURE_TIME = true ]] && alias time_or_not=time

time_or_not (apt-get update > /tmp/last.log 2>&1)
```

The `time` *keyword* doesn't take options (except for `-p` in `bash`), but the format can be set with the `TIMEFORMAT` variable in `bash`. (the `shopt` part is also `bash`-specific, other shells generally don't need that).

Comment: You said "To be able to time a subshell, you need the time keyword". I wonder this behavior documented some where?

Comment: @cuonglm, see `info -f bash --index-search=time`

Answer (score 3):

While an `alias` is one way to do it, this *can* be done with `eval` as well - it's just that you don't so much want to `eval` the command execution as you want to `eval` the command *declaration*.

I like `alias`es - I use 'em all the time, but I like functions better - especially their ability to handle parameters and that they needn't necessarily be expanded in command position as is required for `alias`es.

So I thought maybe you'd want to try this, too:

```
_time() if   set -- "${IFS+IFS=\$2;}" "$IFS" "$@" && IFS='
';      then set -- "$1" "$2" "$*"; unset IFS
             eval "$1 $TIME ${3#"$1"?"$2"?}"
        fi
```

The `$IFS` bit is mainly about `$*`. It's important that the `( subshell bit )` is *also the result of a shell expansion* and so in order to expand the arguments into a parsable string I use `"$*"` *(don't `eval` `"$@"`, by the way, unless you're certain all of the args can be joined on spaces)*. The split delimiter between args in `"$*"` is the first byte in `$IFS`, and so it could be dangerous to proceed without making certain its value. So the function saves `$IFS`, sets it to a `\n`ewline long enough to `set ... "$*"` into `"$3"`, `unset`s it, then resets its value if it previously had one.

Here's a little demo:

```
TIME='set -x; time'
_time \( 'echo "$(echo any number of subshells)"' \
         'command -V time'                        \
         'hash time'                              \
      \) 'set +x'
```

You see I put two commands in the value of `$TIME` there - any number is fine - even none - but be sure it is escaped and quoted properly - and the same goes for the arguments to `_time()`. They will all be concatenated into a single command string when they are executed - but each arg gets its own `\n`ewline and so they can be spread out relatively easily. Or else you can lump them all in one, if you like, and separate them on `\n`ewlines or semi-colons or what-have-you. Just be sure that a single argument represents a command you'd feel comfortable putting on its own line in a script when you call it. `\(`, for example is fine, so long as it is eventually followed with `\)`. Basically the normal stuff.

When `eval` gets the above snippet fed it it looks like:

```
+ eval 'IFS=$2;set -x; time (
echo "$(echo any number of subshells)"
command -V time
hash time
)
set +x'
```

And, its results look like...

#### OUTPUT

```
+++ echo any number of subshells
++ echo 'any number of subshells'
any number of subshells
++ command -V time
time is a shell keyword
++ hash time
bash: hash: time: not found

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
++ set +x
```

The `hash` error indicates that I don't have a `/usr/bin/time` installed *(because I don't)* and `command` let's us know which time is running. The trailing `set +x` is another command executed *after* `time` *(which is possible)* - it is important to be careful with input commands when `eval`ing anything.

Comment: Any reason for not making it `_time() { eval "$TIME $@"; }`? Using a function has the drawback of introducing a different scope for variables (not an issue for subshells)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - because of the quotes in the `"$@"` expansion. I like a single arg to `eval` - it get's scary otherwise. Ummm.... how do you mean about the different scope though? I thought that was just `function` functions...

Comment: `eval` joins its args before executing which is what you are trying to do in a very convoluted way. I meant that `_time 'local var=1; blah'` would make that `var` local to that `_time`, or that `_time 'echo "$#"'` would print the `$#` of that `_time` function, not that of the caller.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I got two tab completes for you here. Right - `eval` concats its args on spaces - which is, as you say, exactly what I do here - though it was not inital intent. I'm going to fix that. `eval`ing `"$*"` as opposed to `"$@"` is a habit I picked up after many run-in's with `command not found` when args were joined at the wrong place. In any case, though the args are ultimately executed in the function, it is simple enough to expand them at invocation, I think. It is what I would do with `"$#"` anyway.

Comment: +1 for the nice twisted piece of hackery though...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - gracias, though I'm not sure which sc I address. This comment thread is weird.